# How to get nullable DateTime out of the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, nullable, sqldatareader

My SQL Server database contains nullable DateTime values. How can I convert them to a nullable DateTime object in my application in C#?

This is what I would think it would look like, but it doesn't:

```
DateTime? dt = (DateTime?) sqldatareader[0];
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Please don't prefix your title with tags.  There are tags for a reason.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A SQL null is not the same as a .NET null; you have to compare against System.DBNull.Value:

```
object sqlDateTime = sqldatareader[0];
DateTime? dt = (sqlDateTime == System.DBNull.Value)
    ? (DateTime?)null
    : Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDateTime);
```

In answer to your comment, the data type of the `Item` property of a `DataReader` is that of the underlying database type. It could be `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime` for a non-null SQL Server database, or `System.DBNull` for a null column, or `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcTypes.SmallDateTime` for an ODBC database, or really just about anything. The only thing you can rely on is that it is of type `object`.

This is also why I suggest using `Convert.ToDateTime()` instead of type coercion to `DateTime`. There is no guarantee a ODBC or whatever date column can be coerced to a .NET `DateTime`. I note your comment specifies a "sqldatareader", and a SQL Server `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime` can indeed be coerced to a `System.DateTime`, but your original question did not tell us that.

For more information on using `DataReader`s, consult [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 33):

I recently found this trick, it's simple:

```
var dt = sqldatareader[0] as DateTime?;
```

Comment: Very nice precise solution! I will be using this from now on instead of the more cumbersome ternary method.

Comment: Can you explain this? I can't understand what and why there is '?' after the DateTime.

Comment: @MDB is just means it is a nullable DateTime

Answer (score 3):

how about creating helper method

```
private static DateTime? MyDateConverter(object o)
{
    return (o == DBNull.Value || o == null) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(o);
}
```

Usage

```
MyDateConverter(sqldatareader[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the value "is DBNull" rather than just null. I posted a small helper class on my blog: http://improve.dk/archive/2007/10/08/handling-dbnulls.aspx

Once you implement the class, you use it like this:

```
DateTime? dt = DBConvert.To<datetime?>(sqldatareader[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I wrote a bunch of extension methods for a DataRow to do just this sort of downcasting...because I hate writing repetitive drivel. Usage is simple:

```
foreach( DataRow dr in someDataTable )
{
  DateTime? dt = dr.CastAsDateTimeNullable( "lastUpdated" ) ;
  int       id = dr.CastAsInt( "transactionID" ) ;
  // etc.
}
```

Here's the piece for DateTime values. Adding implementation for for other data types should be pretty trivial. Wouldn't be difficult to do the same sort of thing to a DataReader if one was so inclined.

I tried to come up with generic methods, but limitations in the way generics are done made it difficult or impossible to do and still get the behavior I wanted (e.g., `null` values rather than `default(T)` — getting default values for SQL NULLs that would make differentiating between `0` and `null`...difficult).

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{

  #region downcast to DateTime

  public static DateTime CastAsDateTime( this DataRow row , int index )
  {
    return toDateTime( row[index] ) ;
  }
  public static DateTime CastAsDateTime( this DataRow row , string columnName )
  {
    return toDateTime( row[columnName] ) ;
  }

  public static DateTime? CastAsDateTimeNullable( this DataRow row , int index )
  {
    return toDateTimeNullable( row[index] );
  }
  public static DateTime? CastAsDateTimeNullable( this DataRow row , string columnName )
  {
    return toDateTimeNullable( row[columnName] ) ;
  }

  #region conversion helpers

  private static DateTime toDateTime( object o )
  {
    DateTime value = (DateTime)o;
    return value;
  }

  private static DateTime? toDateTimeNullable( object o )
  {
    bool  hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
    DateTime? value    = ( hasValue ? (DateTime?) o : (DateTime?) null ) ;
    return value;
  }

  #endregion

  #endregion downcast to DateTime

  // ... other implementations elided .. for brevity

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime? dt = null;

if (sqldatareader[0] != System.DbNull.Value)
{
    dt = (DateTime)sqldatareader[0];
}
```