# Process of comparing sting and int (get from query) value in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to do auto generate the value of a field which type is `int`. Below is my code and it works successfully when I entry one column data manually in database.

But when the DB is totally empty then the output of this query is 'null'. I want when the output of this query is 'null' then the value of `createCode` will be 0 (zero).

```
ConnectionObj.Open();
string query = "SELECT MAX(t_code) FROM teacher_table";
CommandObj.CommandText = query;
int createCode = Convert.ToInt32(CommandObj.ExecuteScalar());
if (createCode == 'null')  //can't compare string and int  
{
    createCode = 0;
    return createCode;
}
else
{
    return createCode;
}
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Error is telling you what is wrong. `createCode` is of type `int` and you are trying to compare it with `null`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nullable out of the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503698/).

Comment: Please read my question again. I think you don;t understand my problem  @Habib

Comment: its which server?? mysql or sql server??

Comment: @Ikr, your `createCode` is `int`, it can never be null, you will get an exception with `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @Habib bro I know that. Please see my whole question with code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `DBNull.Value` before casting it to an int:

```
ConnectionObj.Open();
string query = "SELECT MAX(t_code) FROM teacher_table";
CommandObj.CommandText = query;
object code = CommandObj.ExecuteScalar();
if (code == DBNull.Value)
{
    return 0;
}

return Convert.ToInt32(code);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql, you can use [**IFNULL()**](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/sql-ifnull-example/) like this:

```
string query = "SELECT IFNULL(MAX(t_code),0) FROM teacher_table";
```

In Sql Server you can use [**ISNULL()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) like this:

```
  string query = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(t_code),0) FROM teacher_table";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (createCode == 'null')` to `if (createCode == DBNull.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
object obj = CommandObj.ExecuteScalar();
if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
    return 0;
else
    return Convert.ToInt32(obj);
```

Since your `createCode` is of type `int`, it can never be null, instead your current code will not even compile.