# Specified cast is not valid when casting a nullable datetime returned from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, datetime, casting, sqldatareader

Note: This is *not* a duplicate of [how-to-get-nullable-datetime-out-of-the-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503698/how-to-get-nullable-datetime-out-of-the-database) as I specifically want to avoid using the column index

I have the following object

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code to extract said object from the database

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Deleted FROM MyTable", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (sdr != null && sdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            c.CampID = (int)sdr["ID"];
            c.Deleted = (DateTime?)sdr["Deleted"];
        }
        sdr.Close();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
return c;
```

If deleted date is null I get an error

> Specified cast is not valid

What am I doing wrong? How can I cast a nullable datetime field in this way?

I have two ugly hacks which will get the job done. This:

```
try{
    c.Deleted = (DateTime?)sdr["Deleted"];
}
catch{
    // ignoring a catch makes me feel unclean
}
```

or this

```
if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(sdr["Deleted"].ToString()))
{
    // not quite so bad, but still not very elegant
    c.Deleted = (DateTime?)sdr["Deleted"];
}
```

Is there a cleaner, more elegant way to do this?

Note: I *do not want* to use the field index, ie

```
sdr.GetDateTime(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful

```
c.Deleted = sdr["Deleted"] == DBNull.Value ? 
                  (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["Deleted"]);
```

Comment: The check for `DBNull.Value` is right and clear enough by itself, but why would you use `Convert.ToDateTime` if the value is already known to be a `DateTime`? I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm saying this answer could benefit from an explanation rather than just code.

Answer (score -1):

Test this:

```
c.Deleted = sdr["Deleted"] as DateTime?;
```

Comment: Why default to the current time when the original code returns `null`? Why not just `as DateTime?`?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.