# Exception throw when trying to cast empty value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a query where I receive information from a database in `DataTable`:

```
DataTable estimateCalculation = new DataTable();

estimateCalculation = db.ExeSQLEstimate("usp_Contracted_Calculation", param1, param2);
```

So now I get values as:

```
 var averageContractedAmount = (from DataRow dr in estimateCalculation.Rows select (decimal)dr["AverageContractedAmount"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString("C");
```

But in some scenarios `dr` can be empty so it throws an exception

> System.InvalidCastException: 'The specified conversion is not valid

How can I validate if `dr` returns null, to not try to convert it to decimal?

Comment: You need to compare `dr["AverageContractedAmount"]`, not `estimateCalculation.Rows`, against `DBNull`. See [How to get nullable DateTime out of database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503698/).

Answer (score 1):

I Think you need something simple like this. If I've misunderstood please clarify. (Also Welcome)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    return;
```

It would also be worth looking at [DataRow.IsNull()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRow_IsNull_System_Int32_)

```
if (!dataRow.IsNull());
```

I have not used this myself but looks like it could be ideal for what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this should not gonna be work, because I receive object , I mean [0] but value is `{}` like an empty string

Comment: @Pepe Your procedure returns a single row of data, is this correct?

Comment: I try with   `if(estimateCalculation.Rows == DBNull.Value)`, but  cannot use DBNull.Value in datarow Collection and yes it return only one row

Comment: Rows is a collection so I don't think DBnull.value would work sorry. However that if statement is the same as row count. If you proc returns zero rows it's effectively null (ish) hence why row count would be ideal at that rate.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically 3 options to do the null-check:

1. Call `DataRow.IsNull()`:

   ```
   var row = (from DataRow dr in estimateCalculation.Rows select dr).FirstOrDefault();

   if (row != null && !row.IsNull("AverageContractedAmount"))
   {
       var averageContractedAmount = ((decimal)row["AverageContractedAmount"]).ToString("C");
   }
   ```
2. Compare value to `DbNull.Value`. Note that when column in database contains null, `DataRow["ColumnName"]` does not return `null` but returns `DbNull.Value` instead.

   ```
   var value = (from DataRow dr in estimateCalculation.Rows select dr["AverageContractedAmount"]).FirstOrDefault();

   if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
   {
       var averageContractedAmount = ((decimal)value).ToString("C");
   }
   ```
3. Do run-time **type-check** of the value. This is especially nice when used with C# 7.0 pattern-matching syntax:

   ```
   if ((from DataRow dr in estimateCalculation.Rows select dr["AverageContractedAmount"]).FirstOrDefault() is decimal value)
   {
       var averageContractedAmount = value.ToString("C");
   }
   ```

Sometimes you don't want to do `if-else` branching and just want to convert value to nullable type, usually using ternary conditional operator:

```
var averageContractedAmount = 
    (from DataRow dr in estimateCalculation.Rows
     select (dr.IsNull("Price")
                ? null
                : (decimal?)dr["AverageContractedAmount"])
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    ?.ToString("C");
```